# Unclear how to use winrt::get_cancellation_token for IAsyncAction

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm trying to write a coroutine-based background thread in C++/WinRT that loops on the status of a cancellation token, because I need to take some cleanup action on cancellation.

I'm trying to follow the documentation on MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency#canceling-an-asychronous-operation-and-cancellation-callbacks) but an adaptation of the sample code doesn't compile, and the cancellation_token_t type doesn't appear to be callable.

```
void BackgroundThreadManager::Start()
{
    this->m_Thread = this->RunAsync();
}

void BackgroundThreadManager::Stop()
{
    if (this->m_Thread)
    {
        m_Thread.Cancel();
        m_Thread = nullptr;
    }
}

IAsyncAction BackgroundThreadManager::RunAsync()
{
    winrt::resume_background();
    auto token{ winrt::get_cancellation_token() };
    while (!token())
    {
        co_await this->DoSomethingAsync();
    }
    co_await this->DoSomeCleanupAsync();
}
```

Unfortunately, this fails to compile with "error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments" referring to the "while (!token())" line.

Code agrees with this, as the definition (in base.h) of get_cancellation_token_t is

```
struct get_cancellation_token_t {};
```

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong fundamentally, or the MSDN documentation is out of date. Any clues? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to `co_await` on the `get_cancellation_token()` expression. The `co_await` provides the hook that the library needs to reach in and get the `IAsyncAction` instance that may be canceled. By the way, you also forgot to `co_await` the `resume_background()` expression.

Also, note that coroutines are also automatically canceled at suspension points (`co_await`), so it may be better to use a cancellation callback to ensure that your cancellation logic isn't overlooked.

Comment: Thanks, Kenny. I did have the `co_await` on `get_cancellation_token()` originally but IntelliSense complained that there was no suitable `await_ready` function found. Based on the function signature, I never tried to compile. I see now that it does indeed compile anyway.

Comment: @KennyKerr this is an issue in VS with the current C++/WinRT extension/SDK. I see it too 
https://i.imgur.com/zsNuOX6.png

Comment: This is an IntelliSense bug and is not something that C++/WinRT or the VS extension has any control over. It would greatly help if you report this issue to the VS team here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/62/index.html - that's the best way to get this resolved.